# How to limit service account access in G Suite?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-workspace

I have created a service account for my gsuite domain, which I will use to access one users G Drive to do backups there.

To avoid security issues, I of course need to somehow make sure that the service account can access only this specific users data, and only their GDrive, and nothing else. And also preferably, that it can only be used to write, and not delete any files. (Ofcourse I could use a shared drive to do this, but that may not be possible with my client (rclone via linux), im not sure yet.)

How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If you grant domain-wide delegation to a Service Account, you can impersonate any user in the domain. The Service Account can access the same resources than the user it is impersonating, as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests). And of course, it will not be able to access resources that the impersonated user cannot access.

If your question is whether you can forbid the Service Account from impersonating some users, that's not possible. Any user who has access to the Service Account can impersonate any user in the domain, only the email address has to be specified.

Also, about scopes, the scopes for creating new files ([Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)) are the same than for deleting them ([Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)), so you cannot allow one and forbid the other.

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot limit the service account. Once you enable Domain Wide Delegation on a service account, it has administrator power over the entire G Suite account. Your only option is to use OAuth 2.0 with User Account credentials and apply scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are identities, so you can let a service account access resources by granting it a role, just like you would for any other principal.

See https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/choose-predefined-roles for guide to selecting a role you'll need to assign to your service account to provide granular access to the Drive service.