# How to send service emails via Gmail (machine-2-machine) with secure restrictions?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-iam

How to send service emails

- from my backend with `smtp.google.com` or `Gmail API` while making sure
- the secret stored on the backend server can only be used to send emails from a specific sender?

**Goal**

- send user account activation emails from my backend
- use `smtp.google.com` or `Gmail API` (i.e. no own SMTP server)
- authenticate with OAuth2.0 (i.e. don't enable "less secure apps")

**Current state**

- implemented the email sending part
- for testing, I created a `noreply@**.**` Google Suite account
- for testing, I generated an `accessToken` via [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)
- using the `accessToken` I can send emails via `smtp.googl.com`

**Problem**

- Google [suggests](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to use a `service account` for this
- But to send emails from `no-reply@x.y` I have to enable *Domain-wide Delegation*
- ***Domain-wide delegation* allows to impersonate every domain account**
- the secret stored on the backend should only allow to send mails from `no-reply@**.**`

Comment: Use service accounts and go though the gmail api and not though the smtp server.  As far as i know the smtp server does not support service account authencation only Xoauth2 which isnt going to let you deligate to your no-reply user.   If you want to send emails using a service account your only option is to use google workspace.

Comment: @DaImTo I.e. the easy way would be to keep the `no-reply` user and authenticate (machine-to-machine) via OAuth2 and then use the `authToken` to send via `smtp.google.com` .... so what do I gain by using the service account and GMail API? Seems complicated to only send system emails, not to read any data from gmail.

Comment: The endpoint smtp.google.com does not support Google Cloud service account based authentication. Google does not recommend this either.

Comment: @hb0 what language are you using? I may have some sample code floating around. Service accounts are reasonably strait forward with gmail you just need to set up the delegation properly to the workspace account.  [Managing Delegates](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings)

Comment: @DaImTo Java (with Vert.X). What's more important for me is to understand: (1) do I need to keep the `no-reply@x.y` GSuite account? If so, do I set up the service-account with that account (1a) or with my admin GSuite account (1b)? (2) In case of (1b): How do I make sure the service account only has access to GMail API and can only send (not read) emails (preferably only from `no-reply@x.y`)?

Comment: Current workaround: I generate a refresh token via https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ manually, consenting once with `no-reply` user, and send a refreshToken request to the playground from by backend to get a new access token. This I use to send emails via `smtp.google.com` from the `no-reply` account. I can't believe there is no clean and secure solution for this, but I don't see one right now.

Comment: Last update I guess: I was not able to use the SMTP+OAuth method described in the previous comment as the refresh token got invalidated by google after a few hours without a specific error code. I did not find a way to generate a new refresh token without consent screen but some thing automatable like an API key. I.e. I ended up using the service-account + domain-wide delegation + API key method suggested by @DalmTo, which is why I eventually accepted the aswer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with `send user account activation emails from my server` I am gong to assume that you have a web app.  This web app allows users to register with your system. Now when a user registers with your system you want to automatically send them an account creation email.   Your idea is to use Google rather than setting up your own smtp server and sending these emails from your own system.  Not a bad idea really.

Lets think about this for a minute the emails would need to be sent automatically so you need some kind of service sending them.  To do that you want to use a service account.  Again this is a great idea using a pre authorized service account that you will not need to have a user to authorize the app.

The only issue is that service accounts do not work with normal gmail accounts. To use a service account with Gmail api you need to use a google workspace domain account. The workspace domain admin would then be able to add permissions to the service account letting it act like a user on the domain. In this case your idea of no-reply.

So your workspace domain account would have a user called no-reply.  The domain admin would then configure domain wide delegation to the service account allowing it to pretend that it is the user called no-reply.  For all intents and purposes the service account is the no-reply user.  It will be able to send mails as if they are coming from that user.

For all this to work you will need the workspace account with that user.

Have a look at the following link, it's actually one of Google's better examples it shows how to set up the delegation.

[Perform Google Workspace Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)

Here you create a *service account* with credentials, allow this account to impersonate other users (e.g. the `no-reply` user), to only use the Gmail API and to only use it to send emails.

- the documentation is a bit outdated, you can skip the step `Grant users access to this service account` and create the `service account key` afterwards via the service account edit function: `Manage keys`
- in the step `Domain wide delegation` you need [Google Admin](https://admin.google.com/ac/owl) not the *Google Cloud Platform Admin Console* as in the previous step

Just remember to swap out the lines about

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
```

and use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
```

instead as you want to access the Gmail API and only allow the service account to send (not read) emails

## tip

in the sample code in that link

```
.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
```

userEmail is the email address of the user you want to impersonate in this case no-reply@x.y

So I guess what I am saying is that what you want to do is definitely possible, however, it may be easier just to set up your own SMTP server.

Comment: How can I limit the service account to only impersonate one user (no-reply)? The last step in the `Domain-Wide Delegation` tutorial sounds like it does this, but it only limits admin users to *access* the app, not which users can be impersonated *by the app*. In the sample code I `setServiceAccountUser(no-reply)` but if the service account secret gets hacked, it can change this and impersonate all other domain users, too, right? Sounds scarry ;-)

Comment: To answer my own question: If a service account with `Domain-Wide Delegation` is hacked, it can **impersonate any user on the domain**. You cannot restrict which users can be accessed **by** the service account. See this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066237/how-to-limit-service-account-access-in-g-suite